# Hazelcast spring schema configuration error

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

This file is not changed from 8 months and today we got error on hz:client property related to :

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, 
     but no declaration can be found for element 'hz:client'.
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 
     'https://hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.7.xsd', 
     because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could 
     not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not 
     <xsd:schema>.
```

When i check this https://hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.7.xsd schema is there but elements inside is starting with xs tags. 
What can i do to fix this issue or rewrite client config?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring https://hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.6.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-interation-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="test" class="org.test.impl.TestImpl">
        <property name="hazelcastInstance" ref="hazelcastClient" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:///home/hazelcast.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


     <hz:client id="hazelcastClient">
        <hz:group name="${hazelcast.server.user}" password="${hazelcast.server.password}"/>

         <hz:network connection-attempt-limit="1000"
              connection-attempt-period="3000"
              connection-timeout="1000"
              redo-operation="true"
              smart-routing="true">
         <hz:member>${hazelcast.server.url}:${hazelcast.server.port}</hz:member>
        </hz:network>
        </hz:client>
</beans>
```

Comment: the error you posted is referring `hazelcast-spring-3.7.xsd` while the XML uses `hazelcast-spring-3.6.xsd`. Can you please double-check it?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the schema with this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.7.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```

And now is working but i still doesn`t know why . Can someone explain me?

Comment: What is your exact Hazelcast version? Local schema resolution for HTTPS was added only in Hazelcast 3.7 and backported into 3.6.4. See https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/8604

Comment: We use hazelcast 3.7. And everything was working great until today... Without any deploy on the server just after 1 restart the server stoped working. That's why i don't know do they changed something and why with this schema it is working.